# what index to use for query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization

**controller**

```
@from = params[:from] ? 4.hours.since(Time.zone.parse(params[:from])) : today_start_time
@to = params[:to] ? 4.hours.since(Time.zone.parse(params[:to])) : @from
@franchise = current_user_accessible_franchises_filtered
@orders_type = Restaurant::DELIVERY_TYPES.detect { |t| t == params[:orders_type]} || Restaurant::DELIVERY_TYPES.first
@limit = (params[:limit] || 250).to_i

@to = 48.hours.since(@to) if @to == @from && @from == today_start_time

start_time = @from.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
end_time = 24.hours.since(@to).utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

@orders = Order
  .includes(:address, :franchise, :customer, :ordered_items, :rests, :driver)
  .where(
    "((orders.created_at >= ? AND orders.created_at <= ?) OR (orders.delivery_target >= ? AND orders.delivery_target <= ?)) AND orders.franchise_id in (?) AND orders.delivery_type = ?",
    start_time, end_time, start_time, end_time, @franchise, @orders_type
  )
  .order("orders.status desc, orders.id desc")
```

**log**

> (23732.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `orders`.`id`) FROM `orders` LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN `addresses` ON `addresses`.`id` = `orders`.`address_id`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `franchises` ON `franchises`.`id` =
>   `orders`.`franchise_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `customers` ON
>   `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   `ordered_items` ON `ordered_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN `ordered_items` `ordered_items_orders_join` ON
>   `ordered_items_orders_join`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   `restaurants` ON `restaurants`.`id` =
>   `ordered_items_orders_join`.`restaurant_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `drivers`
>   ON `drivers`.`id` = `orders`.`driver_id` WHERE (((orders.created_at >=
>   '2015-03-01 10:00' AND orders.created_at <= '2015-03-04 10:00') OR
>   (orders.delivery_target >= '2015-03-01 10:00' AND
>   orders.delivery_target <= '2015-03-04 10:00')) AND orders.franchise_id
>   in
>   (3,31,4,22,37,2,36,17,34,30,19,20,21,18,27,13,25,16,35,24,32,33,1,12,28,23,14,26,29,8,11)
>   AND orders.delivery_type = 'Mr. Delivery Restaurant')

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED
 SELECT  DISTINCT `orders`.id
    FROM  `orders`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `addresses`     ON `addresses`.`id` = `orders`.`address_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `franchises`    ON `franchises`.`id` = `orders`.`franchise_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `customers`     ON `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `ordered_items` ON `ordered_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `ordered_items` `ordered_items_orders_join`
                                     ON `ordered_items_orders_join`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `restaurants`   ON `restaurants`.`id` = `ordered_items_orders_join`.`restaurant_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `drivers`       ON `drivers`.`id` = `orders`.`driver_id`
    WHERE  ( ( (orders.created_at >= '2015-02-01 10:00'
           AND  orders.created_at <= '2015-02-04 10:00')
                     OR  (orders.delivery_target >= '2015-02-01 10:00'
                     AND  orders.delivery_target <= '2015-02-04 10:00') )
              AND  orders.franchise_id in (3,31,4,22,37,2,36,17,34,30,
                       19,20,21,18,27,13,25,16,35,24,32,33,1,12,28,23,14,26,29, 8,11 )
              AND  orders.delivery_type = 'Mr. Delivery Restaurant'
           )
    ORDER BY  orders.status desc,
              orders.id desc
    LIMIT  250;

+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                | key                             | key_len | ref                                                     | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders                    | ref    | index_orders_on_created_at,index_orders_on_delivery_target,index_orders_on_franchise_id,index_orders_on_delivery_type,my_idx | index_orders_on_delivery_type   | 77      | const                                                   | 549769 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | addresses                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                         | 4       | mrd_staging_new.orders.address_id                       |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | franchises                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                         | 4       | mrd_staging_new.orders.franchise_id                     |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customers                 | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                         | 4       | mrd_staging_new.orders.customer_id                      |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ordered_items             | ref    | index_ordered_items_on_order_id                                                                                              | index_ordered_items_on_order_id | 5       | mrd_staging_new.orders.id                               |      2 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ordered_items_orders_join | ref    | index_ordered_items_on_order_id                                                                                              | index_ordered_items_on_order_id | 5       | mrd_staging_new.orders.id                               |      2 |   100.00 | Distinct                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | restaurants               | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                         | 4       | mrd_staging_new.ordered_items_orders_join.restaurant_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | drivers                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                         | 4       | mrd_staging_new.orders.driver_id                        |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**indices on Orders table**

```
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name           | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| orders |          0 | PRIMARY                               |            1 | id                    | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_delivered_at          |            1 | delivered_at          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_updated_at            |            1 | updated_at            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_created_at            |            1 | created_at            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_pickup_at             |            1 | pickup_at             | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_coupon_id             |            1 | coupon_id             | A         |       14856 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_driver_id             |            1 | driver_id             | A         |        4159 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_delivery_target       |            1 | delivery_target       | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_franchise_id          |            1 | franchise_id          | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | idx_for_customers_report              |            1 | customer_id           | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | idx_for_customers_report              |            2 | delivered_at          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | idx_for_customers_report              |            3 | created_at            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | idx_for_customers_report              |            4 | status                | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | idx_for_customers_report              |            5 | franchise_id          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            1 | id                    | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            2 | created_at            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            3 | delivered_at          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            4 | status                | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            5 | franchise_id          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            6 | customer_id           | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | orders_fetch_index_for_revenue_report |            7 | address_id            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_address_id            |            1 | address_id            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_customer_id           |            1 | customer_id           | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_delivery_type         |            1 | delivery_type         | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_status                |            1 | status                | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | index_orders_on_should_pay_restaurant |            1 | should_pay_restaurant | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            1 | created_at            | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            2 | delivery_target       | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            3 | franchise_id          | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            4 | delivery_type         | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            5 | status                | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| orders |          1 | my_idx                                |            6 | id                    | A         |      935943 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

**total quantity**

```
mysql> select count(*) from orders;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   965520 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)
```

**I have tried to add a composite index**

```
create index my_idx on orders(created_at, delivery_target, franchise_id, delivery_type);
```

**even**

```
create index my_idx on orders(created_at, delivery_target, franchise_id, delivery_type, status, id);
```

but without success.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: This is a strange query. You have a gazillion LEFT JOIN operations, but not one column from any of the joined tables appears in your result set. Also, you use DISTINCT on the PK. So, afaik the JOINs make no difference to the result. What are you trying to accomplish with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INDEX(delivery_type,  -- because it is  "= constant"
      franchise_id)   -- the only other viable column
```

Indexing any column hiding in an `OR` is virtually futile.

I do question your `ORDER BY status` while doing `DISTINCT id` and no mention of `status`.

You *may* be able to speed it up by turning the `OR` into a `UNION`:

```
      ( SELECT  orders.status, orders.id
            FROM  ...
            JOIN  ...
            WHERE  orders.created_at ...
              AND  ...
            ORDER BY  ...
            LIMIT  250 
      )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
      ( SELECT  orders.status, orders.id
            FROM  ...
            JOIN  ...
            WHERE  orders.delivery_target ... -- note difference
              AND  ...
            ORDER BY  ...
            LIMIT  250 
      )
    ORDER BY  status DESC, id DESC -- yes, again
    LIMIT  250; -- yes, again
```

But for this reformulation to work well, there needs to be new indexes.  I am not sure whether these

```
INDEX(delivery_type, franchise_id, created_at),
INDEX(delivery_type, franchise_id, delivery_target),
```

or these

```
INDEX(delivery_type, created_at),
INDEX(delivery_type, delivery_target),
```

would work better.  Add all 4; do `EXPLAIN` to see which ones it uses.